# Why Lambert answer doesn't satisfy the original equation in WolframAlpha

Tags: calculus, lambert-w

I solved the differential equation $y(y'+a)=b$ and found the answer
$$ay+b\ln(y-\frac{b}{a})=-a^2(t+c)$$
as I wanted the explicity form of my solution, by giving it to WolframAlpha at address
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%28y%27%2Ba%29%3Db
it is in terms of Lambert function:
$$y(x) = \frac{b}{a} \left(W\left(-\frac{1}{b}e^{-\frac{xa^2}{b} + \frac{Ca^2}{b} - 1}\right) + 1\right)$$
but my handy answer is
\begin{align}
u=y-\frac{b}{a} \hspace{1cm} \Rightarrow  \hspace{1cm}
& b\ln u=-a^2t-a^2C-au-b\\
& u=e^{-\frac{a^2t}{b} - \frac{a^2C}{b} - 1}e^{-\frac{a}{b}u}\\
& \frac{a}{b}u\ e^{\frac{a}{b}u}=\frac{a}{b}\ e^{-\frac{a^2t}{b} - \frac{a^2C}{b} - 1}\\
& \frac{a}{b}u=W\left(\frac{a}{b}\ e^{-\frac{a^2t}{b} - \frac{a^2C}{b} - 1}\right)\\
y=u+\frac{b}{a} \hspace{1cm} \Rightarrow  \hspace{1cm}
& y(x) = \frac{b}{a} \left(W\left(\frac{\color{red}{a}}{b}e^{-\frac{xa^2}{b} + \frac{Ca^2}{b} - 1}\right) + 1\right)
\end{align}
which is differ from Wolfram answer. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I checked the answer handy, it doesn't satisfy the DE!

Comment: ok, thanks :)..

Comment: MAPLE gives the same result as Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I found the solution as $ay+b\ln{(b-ay)}=-a^2 (t+C)$. Sympy solve $y(t)$ as $\left[ \frac{b \left(W\left(- \frac{e^{\frac{- C a^{2} - a^{2} t - b}{b}}}{b}\right) + 1\right)}{a}\right]$.

Comment: @adzetto yes, I found something like you.